# What kind of variable should I use for Genre

Tags: java, arrays, variables, arraylist, enums

I m writing a program in java, (spring boot). It is about TvSeries administration.
what kind of variable should I use for Genre. A TvSeries can have multiple genre.
Should I use Array, ArrayList, Enum  or anything else ?

```
package com.example.payex;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class TvShow 
{
    @Id
    private long id ;
    private String name ;
    private String[] genre = new String[10] ;
    private float rating ;
    private int episodeCount ;
    private int releasedEpisodeCount ;
    private String summary;
    private String imdbLink;

    public TvShow( long id, String name, String genre,  float rating, int episodeCount, int releasedEpisodeCount, String summary, String imdbLink ) 
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.genre = genre ;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.episodeCount = episodeCount;
        this.releasedEpisodeCount = releasedEpisodeCount;
        this.summary = summary;
        this.imdbLink = imdbLink;
    }
    
    public TvShow() {}
}
```

Comment: A Set, probably, because ordering and multiplicity of genres likely doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Television genres are also classified with a *format*, which subsequently includes a *type*.
*[Wikipedia – List of television formats and genres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_television_formats_and_genres)*.

If these are of importance, you can utilize a class structure, which can reference *enum* values.

Here is an example using the values provided by Wikipedia.
Basic usage would be as follows.

```java
Genre genre = new Genre(new Format(Formats.SHOW), Genres.COOKING_SHOW);
```

```java
class Genre {
    Format format;
    Genres genre;

    public Genre(Format format, Genres genre) {
        this.format = format;
        this.genre = genre;
    }
}

class Format {
    Formats format;
    Types type;

    public Format(Formats format, Types type) {
        this.format = format;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Format(Formats format) {
        this.format = format;
    }
}

enum Formats {
    CLIP,
    DOCUFICTION,
    DOCUMENTARY,
    SINGLE_EPISODE,
    MADE_FOR_TV_FILM,
    FRANCHISE,
    MINISERIES,
    MICRO_SERIES,
    MOCKUMENTARY,
    PILOT,
    PREQUEL,
    REBOOT,
    REMAKE,
    SEGMENT,
    SEQUEL,
    SERIAL,
    SERIES,
    SHORT,
    SHOW,
    SPECIAL,
    SPIN_OFF,
    PILOT_EPISODE
}

enum Types {
    ANIMATED,
    ANIME,
    COMPUTER_ANIMATION,
    STOP_MOTION,
    TRADITIONAL_ANIMATION,
    LIVE_ACTION,
    MODELS,
    PUPPETRY
}

enum Genres {
    ACTION_SERIES,
    ADVENTURE_SERIES,
    ANIMATED_SERIES,
    CARTOON_SERIES,
    ANTHOLOGY_SERIES,
    ART,
    CHILDRENS_SERIES,
    COOKING_SHOW,
    DAYTIME_TELEVISION,
    DRAMATIC_PROGRAMMING,
    DOCUMENTARY,
    DOCUDRAMA,
    DRAMALITY,
    MEDICAL_DRAMA,
    MOCKUMENTARY,
    EDUCATIONAL,
    FACTUAL_TELEVISION,
    INSTRUCTIONAL,
    FANTASY,
    GAME_SHOW,
    LATE_NIGHT_TELEVISION,
    MUSIC_TELEVISION,
    NEWS_SHOW,
    CURRENT_AFFAIRS,
    TABLOID_TELEVISION,
    POLICE_PROCEDURAL,
    DETECTIVE_FICTION,
    PRIME_TIME_TELEVISION,
    PUBLIC_AFFAIRS_BROADCASTING,
    REALITY,
    RELIGIOUS,
    SCIENCE_FICTION,
    SERIAL,
    COMEDY,
    SITCOM,
    ROMCOM,
    STAND_UP_COMEDY,
    SOAP_OPERA,
    SPORTS,
    TELENOVELA,
    INFOMERCIALS,
    VARIETY_SHOW,
    WESTERN_SERIES,
    SPACE_WESTERN
}
```